# The way to use JFLAP to do a Pushdown Automaton

Tags: pushdown-automaton, automaton, jflap

I need to create a Pushdown Automaton with JFLAP that recognizes the following language:

[image]

What steps need to be taken to do it? And how does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this question is better suited for [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) but I'll add my solution anyway.

#### Forming an example

It's actually easier than it looks, let's consider for the sake of an example that we have the following values for our occurrences:

```
n = 2
m = 3
p = 1
```

This should allow us to form the following string:

> a<sup>2</sup>b<sup>3</sup>c<sup>1</sup>a<sup>1+3</sup>b<sup>2</sup> = aabbbcaaaabb

#### Forming logical understanding

From this we need to determine which symbols we need to keep a track of.

1. We know that the outer symbols occur `n` times and that `n,m ≥ 1` so we need to keep a track of `n` here and we require it to occur **at least** once.
2. We know that `q = p+m` and `m` also occurs **at least** so we need to keep a track of the occurrences of `m`.
3. If `q = p+m` we also need to keep an occurrence of `p` but note that **`p` can also *not* occur** because it is stated that `p ≥ 0`.

#### Forming a formal definition

We let our PDA *P* to be the following PDA:

*P* = (Q, Σ, Γ, τ, q<sub>0</sub>, Z, q<sub>6</sub>)

Where:

- Q is the set of states in our d-PDA
- Σ is the input symbol containing the string
- Γ is the stack symbol containing the set Γ = {a,b}
- q<sub>0</sub> is our initial (start) state
- Z is our stack symbol `#`
- q<sub>6</sub> is our final (end) state

#### Forming a pushdown automaton

So from this we can form the following automaton (in JFLAP):

[image: JFLAP PDA]

So here, we are just keeping a track the symbols as mentioned above but an important thing to note here is `q3` where the transition for `c` is a **0 or more** transition.

We also use the symbol `#` as the stack symbol.

#### Simulation

If we simulate this PDA with the input as specified above (`aabbbcaaaabb`), we get the following results:

[image: simulation]